# phpmyadmin shows php code, but actual application code works fine

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I am hosting my application on AWS server. I configured Virtualmin on it and created a new virtual server - `mydomain.td.lr`, and it created a user - mydomain.

I configured a virtual host for it too from the virtualmin interface.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#500" "#500"
ServerName mydomain.td.lr
ServerAlias www.mydomain.td.lr
ServerAlias webmail.mydomain.td.lr
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/mydomain
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.td.lr_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.td.lr_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /var/www/public_html/mydomain>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mydomain/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.mydomain.td.lr
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.td.lr:20000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
Alias /dav /home/mydomain/public_html
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "mydomain.td.lr"
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "mydomain.td.lr statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://mydomain.td.lr:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://mydomain.td.lr:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
</VirtualHost>
```

This got appended to the `httpd.conf`.

When I open my application at `mydomain.td.lr`, the application shows up; but when I open phpmhyadmin, I see a php code there.

*Also, when I see source code of phpmyadmin page, all the php code is commented out and code inside html which is php is being shown*

I reinstalled phpmyadmin on the server, but still no success.
What went wrong with the configuration???

Answer (score 1):

Removing these two lines does the job for me.

```
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made modification in `apache.conf` which exists in `/etc/phpmyadmin` folder?

I think you have to also make entry in `phpmyadmin apache.conf` and make sure that short tag is not commented in `php.ini` file.

Hope this will help.

Comment: in /etc/phpMyAdmin, there is only one file - config.inc.php

Comment: and short tag in php.ini is On

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was

```
php_admin_value engine Off
```

in  httpd.config Virtual host section.

Once disabled,

```
# php_admin_value engine Off
```

everything (virtual sites, phpMyAdmin) worked just fine.

Consider security issue, but mod_php could be enabled either in custom or default template > Apache_website under Virtualmin Server Template